# Install and configure SSL with TeamCity using cert generated from a global CA

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, teamcity

UPDATE:

```
Updated to be more specific with what I'm dealing with.

I thought I was on the right path before, but now things just feel more obscure.
```

I have no experience with Apache/Tomcat/Whatever TeamCity is running under, pretty much only worked in IIS before, and I am having a hard time understanding how to install a SSL certificate to use TeamCity with https.

I have an SSL Cert from a global CA but I am having a hard time with the instructions [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

I imported my cert into a keystore and I configured my server.xml file to point at my keystore following the directions.  However, when I go to my site it says there is a problem with my certificate.  It seems like the instructions from the CA, the instructions from TeamCity, and the instructions from Apache (which team city links to) are all different.

Can anyone help explain the steps I'm missing/skipping?

Note, this is running on a Windows box if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you talking about Apache or Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

To install the certificate on apache2 you'll need to edit either your httpd.conf or SSL.conf file to contain three entries:

SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/apacheconf/ssl.crt/server.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your/apacheconf/ssl.key/server.key

You may need to check that you've installed OpenSSL and mod_ssl.so.

Comment: I couldn't find these .conf files so I think maybe I don't know what it is running.  Edited question to be more specific.

Comment: You're going to need more information about what you're running.  Your TeamCity client server is running off Java.  You need to know if you're using Tomcat, or if you have a more complex setup with both the Apache webserver and Tomcat.  Look at your Widows services for Tomcat and Apache.

Comment: I don't see Apache or Tomcat in my windows services.  I only see TeamCity Web Server.  In the TeamCity conf directory I have a server.xml which has comments regarding Catalina as the service.  Sorry, I don't know what information is helpful here.

Comment: Catalina is Tomcat's servlet container.  Do you see a service called Catalina running?

Comment: Nope.  I'm going to email JetBrains and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

Based on your info and the comments, it runs over a modified Tomcat. *It must be easy for you modify the file "server.xml"* and locate the parameters needed for SSL Certificate.

Read this document as a base [Tomcat SSL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) (full). The section "Edit the Tomcat Configuration File" will explain you how to modify the file to use .key and .crt files.

Maybe, if your certificate is in PEM or PFX format you need to use OpenSSL (refer to [Convert Certificates](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) for the more common commands) to transform it in the format needed by Tomcat.

Good luck

**Note**: Maybe there's more than a server.xml file, you must modify the one that configures de server, not the one that configures the application that runs over.